# Integration property proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $c>0$ and let $f :[ac,bc]\to\mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable. Working directly with the definition of the integral, show that
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(cx)\ dx = \frac{1}{c}\int_{ac}^{bc}f(x) \ dx.$$
More generally, show that
$$\int_{a-d/c}^{b-d/c} f(cx+d)\ dx = \frac{1}{c}\int_{ac}^{bc} f(x)\ dx.$$

I have most of the pieces that I need to solve this, specifically that the definition of the integral is just the Riemann sum. However, I'm stuck and not sure how to start this as far as a good proof goes.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If $(x_0=a,x_1,....,x_n=b)$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ then $(cx_0=ca,cx_1,....,cx_n=cb)$ is a partition of $[ca,cb]$, and similarly the other way around. The result follows more or less from the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) = cx = u$, then $(g^{-1})'(x) = \frac1c$.

By definition, $\int f(g(x))dx = \int f(u)(g^{-1})'(u)du$

then
$$\int_a^b f(g(x))dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u)(g^{-1})'(u)du = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u)\frac{1}{c}du = \frac1c \int_{ca}^{cb} f(u)du $$
On the right hand side, you can replace $u$ with $x$.

The second equation which is a more general case with $g(x) = cx+d$ can be done with the same approach.